# Merging JSONs based on condition

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft

Please help me to get the below output.

Based on Input1 and Input2 I have get the output. If Id matches then I need to have PATCH method if it does not then I need to have POST method.

If the Id ("ID": "123456") does not exist in input1 then it is POST else it is PATCH.

**Input1: **

```
{
  "prod": [
    {
      "Id": "123456",
      "value": "ABC"
    },
    {
      "Id": "123456",
      "value": "DEF"
    },
    {
      "Id": "987654",
      "value": "DEF"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Input2:**

```
{
  "ProdInfo": {
    "Prod": [
      {
        "Id": "123456",
        "value1": "LMN"
      },
      {
        "Id": "123456",
        "value1": "OPQ"
      },
      {
        "Id": "654321",
        "value1": "OPQ"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "output": [
    {
      "Request": [
        {
          "method": "PATCH",
          "body": {
            "ID": "123456",
            "Value": "ABC;DEF;LMN;OPQ"
          }
        },
        {
          "method": "POST",
          "body": {
            "ID": "654321",
            "Value": "OPQ"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please specify in more detail how the output is constructed from the inputs. How are the values built? Are the ids grouped? Explain what PATCH and POST mean in this context or how to output them.

Comment: Based on the Id in both input1 and input2 we need to join the Value in the output. if the Id exist in both input1 and input2 then the method in the output is "PATCH".

If the Id in the Input1 does not exist in Input2 we need to still join the Value in the output. If the Id exist in input1 and does not exist in Input2 then the method in the output is "POST"

Basically it is like, I am checking if the data exist in the target (which is Input1), If it exist then I will updating it (PATCH) if it does not then I will Creating it (POST)

I hope this will help to answer my question.

Comment: You are missing that the output is obviously grouped by id and that the values are concatenated together. Those details should be provided in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can approach this problem by grouping by id, then use pluck() to get the key values in a way that can be mapped into the desired output. I added a function to encapsulate some of the inner complexity.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var input1={
  "prod": [
    {
      "Id": "123456",
      "value": "ABC"
    },
    {
      "Id": "123456",
      "value": "DEF"
    }
  ]
}.prod groupBy ($.Id)

fun joinValues(v1,v2)=(v1 default [] ++ v2 default []) joinBy  ";"
---
{
    "output": [
        {
            Request: 
                payload.ProdInfo.Prod 
                    groupBy ($.Id)
                    pluck ((value, key, index) -> {
                        method: if (namesOf(input1) contains (key as String)) "PATCH" else "POST",
                        body: {
                            ID: key,
                            Value: joinValues(input1[key as String].*value, value.*value1)
                        }
                    })
        }
    ]
}
```

Input payload (equal to input2)

```json
{
  "ProdInfo": {
    "Prod": [
      {
        "Id": "123456",
        "value1": "LMN"
      },
      {
        "Id": "123456",
        "value1": "OPQ"
      },
      {
        "Id": "654321",
        "value1": "OPQ"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Output:

```json
{
  "output": [
    {
      "Request": [
        {
          "method": "PATCH",
          "body": {
            "ID": "123456",
            "Value": "ABC;DEF;LMN;OPQ"
          }
        },
        {
          "method": "POST",
          "body": {
            "ID": "654321",
            "Value": "OPQ"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: thanks @aled. It works. I have a small change in the input2 ( I have updated the same in the above example). in the Input2 it is actually "value1": "LMN".

Please help how to handle in this scenario.

Comment: I updated the function to join two lists of strings, one from the values and the other from value1s in each input. I should have made that originally since I think it is a bit more clear anyway.

Comment: thanks @aled. It works perfectly fine. I have one more last requirement. Please help me with it. 
If the Id in Input1 exists and it does not exist then in the output I need to create one more array with DELETE method. I have update the above examples. Please check and guide me.

Comment: Please create a new question instead of expanding the existing question.

Comment: sure @aled. I have reverted the changes. It looks like it not allowing me to upvote because I am not having enough reputation. But I have accepted the answer

Answer (score 0):

i hope this helps you!

**Code**:

```html
%dw 2.0
var prods = (input1.prod ++ input2.ProdInfo.Prod) map ((item, index) -> {Id: item.Id, value: if (item.value1 != null) item.value1 else item.value})
var ids = prods.Id distinctBy $
var prodsGrouped = ids map (id, index) -> (prods filter ($.Id == id))
output application/json  
---
{
  "output": [

      "Request": prodsGrouped map {
        "method": if (sizeOf($.Id) == 1) "POST" else "PATCH",
        "Body": {
          "ID": $.Id[0],
          "Value  ": $.value joinBy ";"
        }
      }
  ]
}
```

**Output**

```js
{
  "output": [
    {
      "Request": [
        {
          "method": "PATCH",
          "Body": {
            "ID": "123456",
            "Value  ": "ABC;DEF;LMN;OPQ"
          }
        },
        {
          "method": "POST",
          "Body": {
            "ID": "987654",
            "Value  ": "DEF"
          }
        },
        {
          "method": "POST",
          "Body": {
            "ID": "654321",
            "Value  ": "OPQ"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```